# Automatically set all the fields (private) in a class

Tags: java

I wonder whether it is possible to set all the fields (with some exceptions) in a given class to a certain value in a loop. Say we have a class with many fields and we want to populate its values not manually by accessors but in semi-automatic way. 
In Java there is a way to show all the field in a given class. This code does so:

```
for (Field field : MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println(field);
}
```

There is also way to set values:

```
License license = new License();
for (Field field : License.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
   System.out.println(field);
   field.set(license, 99);
}
```

However, it fails with an exception `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: can not access a member of class License with modifiers "private`. So I would like to now whether it is possible to set values for private fields in a given class.

Comment: Remember that even if something is possible, it doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea.

Comment: @Kayaman Please feel free to provide some details. Link to documentation would suffice.

Comment: I'm not sure where this particular bad programming practice would be documented. Using reflection to access private members is dubious, and if you have to do it you probably shouldn't write the code yourself, but use a library that provides the functionality for you. In this case I'm talking about the end functionality, i.e. the root reason why you want to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allow the access by calling `field.setAccessible(true);`

Comment: I have just found it out on my own. I will accept your answer thought.

Comment: @menteith If you found it out on your own, you can add an answer to your own question as well (this is encouraged). Anyway, obsolete now that we already have this answer.